# How to get return value of shell command in Mono C#

Tags: mono

I want to know how to interact with shell from Mono and I can't seem to find very much information about this. For example, I want to return the output of "ls" and stick it into a variable - Is this even possible?

Here's what I have so far:

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ls";
        proc.Start ();
        proc.Close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the shell output. Please try the following -

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/ls",  "-l")
                   {
                     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                     UseShellExecute = false
                   };
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
//The output of the shell command will be in the outPut variable after the 
//following line is executed
var outPut = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```